# Python: Getting the Sum of a Lambda Function

Tags: python, math, lambda

I'm trying to get the sum of all the prime numbers below 2,000,000 in Python, using a lambda function. (I've bruteforced it, but that takes much too long, and I want a better solution.) Here is what I have so far:

```
def isPrime(n):
    for x in range(2, int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n%x==0: return False
    return True


print reduce(lambda x: isPrime(x), [range(200)])
```

Now, this just prints numbers incrementing from 1 to 200, so I don't think reduce is working =\

Anyone have any tips?

Comment: The function passed to `reduce()` takes *two* arguments; the previous result and the current element from the sequence. Did you want to use `filter()` instead?

Comment: And `[range(200)]` creates a list with *one* element, another list of 200 numbers. `reduce()` does *nothing* when there is only one element in the input list, and returns that input element.

Comment: I am giving it two arguments; the sequence is in brackets, range(200).

Comment: When I use filter, it just returns boolean values.

Comment: You need to use `reduce(..., range(200))`, and even that is wrong because I don't think you understand what `reduce()` *does*.

Comment: No, `filter()` returns the values for which the function returns True. You must've been using `map()` instead.

Comment: So how would I use filter, then?

Comment: Yes, use `filter()`, as the answer below tells you to do too. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few odd things going on with your code.

- I think you actually want to be using [`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter), not [`reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce).
- `lambda x: isPrime(x)` is equivalent to `isPrime` (after all, `isPrime` is already a function that returns the result of `isPrime`).
- `[range(200)]` creates a nested list.  The only element in the outer list is a list with the numbers from 0 to 200.  I think you just want the single list.

So, try the following:

```
print filter(isPrime, range(200))
```

Comment: Is there any way I can increment the values by 2 so I can have it more efficient? I'm using sum(filter(isPrime, range(2000000))) and I need this to be faster than the brute force method.

Comment: Your isPrime function is the brute force part of the method. Improving it will make much larger improvements in performance than any optimization of the summation of the elements.

Comment: @Tetramputechture Use `range(1, 200, 2)` to increment by 2, but Tyler is right, your focus should be on a better prime testing function.  [This answer should help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2068548/505154).

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of things wrong here. The first is that you can replace `lambda x: isPrime(x)` with simply `isPrime`. Functions are first class in Python, which means you can just pass them around in the same way as integers or strings. The second is that you are passing a list of lists; `[range(200)]` is a list containing the return value of `range(200)` range returns a list so you are only reducing a single value. This gets around the third problem, which is that your reduce function should accept 2 arguments, as reduce calls the function passed on pairs of items as a time. As it is, there is only one item so the function is called 0 times and the first item on list is returned.

What I suspect you want to do is to filter the list, you can use the `filter` function to do this or you can use a list comprehension which would look like this:

```
[x for x in range(200) if isPrime(x)]
```

Comment: It shows :P In answer to your increment by 2 question try `help(range)` in the Python command line.

Comment: just oneeee more thing :) why does it print 15 when I type
print sum([x for x in range(1, 10, 2) if isPrime(x)])

Comment: Don't forget to add the 2 back. 2 is prime and you skip it with range(1, 10, 2). Plus it's probably better to start with 3. The primality of 1 is not an easy question to answer. ie: range(3, 10, 2)